# MySQL trigger insert after insert into another table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to add a foreign key into `tblprowareinventory` whenever I insert into `tblprowareproducts`:

[image: phpmyadmin]
tblProwareproducts

```
CREATE TABLE `tblprowareproducts` (
  `ItemID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ItemCode` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `itemDescription` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `Strand` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `UnitCost` double NOT NULL,
  `SaleCost` double NOT NULL,
  `CategoryID_fk` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `tblprowareproducts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ItemID`),
  ADD KEY `CategoryID_fk` (`CategoryID_fk`);


ALTER TABLE `tblprowareproducts`
  MODIFY `ItemID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `tblprowareproducts`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tblprowareproducts_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryID_fk`) REFERENCES `tblprowarecategory` (`PCategoryID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

tblProwareinventory

```
CREATE TABLE `tblprowareinventory` (
  `inventoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ItemID_FK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DateOfInventory` date NOT NULL,
  `CurrentQuantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TotalQuantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DeliveredQuantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PhysicalCount` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `tblprowareinventory`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`inventoryID`),
  ADD KEY `ItemID_FK` (`ItemID_FK`);


ALTER TABLE `tblprowareinventory`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tblprowareinventory_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ItemID_FK`) REFERENCES `tblprowareproducts` (`ItemID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO tblprowareinventory(ItemID_FK) 
VALUES ((SELECT ItemID FROM tblprowareproducts))
```

but I get this error:

[image: error]

Comment: Is inventoryid an auto_increment?

Comment: Yes, it auto_increment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `CREATE TRIGGER` statement:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER AddToInventory AFTER INSERT ON tblprowareproducts
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO tblprowareinventory (ItemID_FK) VALUES (NEW.ItemID);
   END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

**Note:** You have to remove your current trigger on phpMyAdmin or with the following statement: `DROP TRIGGER AddToInventory;` to successfully run this `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.

---

The `TRIGGER` successfully add a new row to the `tblprowareinventory` table with the `NEW.ItemID`, but you defined a `PRIMARY KEY` on the `inventoryID` of `tblprowareinventory` table. That's OK, but after trying `INSERT` a second row on `tblprowareinventory` table, you should get an error:

> #1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

The `TRIGGER` tries to `INSERT` a second row on `tblprowareinventory` table with 0 on the `inventoryID` column. This is not possible because 0 can only exists once on the `inventoryID` column.

You can solve this issue using a `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the `inventoryID` column too:

```
ALTER TABLE `tblprowareinventory` MODIFY `inventoryID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

To `INSERT` a new row on `tblprowareproducts` table I used the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO `tblprowareproducts` (`ItemID`, `ItemCode`, `itemDescription`, `Strand`, `UnitCost`, `SaleCost`, `CategoryID_fk`) 
    VALUES (NULL, '111', '111', '111', '1', '1', '1')
```

Comment: `ItemID` is auto increment or user defined?

Comment: it is set to auto increment

Comment: can you edit your question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statements of `tblprowareinventory` and `tblprowareproducts`?